# fatal error regarding sqlserv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect my php with sql server 2008. I've downloaded the microsoft package providing the dll's.

I've put this dll in my ext folder:

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

and modified my .ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

and here's my php code:

```
<?php

    $servername = "kingston\SQLServer2000";
    $connection_info = array("Database"=>"SIIG_DAT_DESENV","UID"=>"MATRIZ\jmartins", "PWD"=>"jonjon3");
    $conn = sqlserv_connect($servername,$sconnection_info);

    if($conn){
        echo "Consegui!";
    }else{
        echo "fail :(";
    }   
?>
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlserv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 5
```

Anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running on windows. You can try the following steps:

1. Install Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098.
   Install in php extensions folder ...\php...\ext\
2. Add following 2 lines in php.ini
   extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll 
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
3. Install Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065
4. A nice tutorial exists in http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/08/how-to-let-php-get-data-from-microsoft-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Do i really have to install this SQL Server 2012 native client? I'm trying to connect with Sql Server 2008. I'm using php 4.3 by the way.

Comment: I did this for 2012 and php 5.3. you should check if you need to install an earlier driver. I think this is the step you are missing.

Comment: And another thing. It seems that i need to connect php 4.3 and Sql Server 2012. Is it possible with these drivers? Or do i have to update my PHP version?

Comment: I don't know. But updating to the latest PHP is a good idea anyways.

Comment: Hm...I'll have to check it out with the rest of the team, because this particular project is being used by lots of clients. Maybe updating the php could cause some problems, but then again, it's my first time messing around with it.

Comment: in that case, just look for drivers compatible with your version. But it seems that you are just missing the  Native Client now.